Docker PHP-FPM port conflict
I'm currently learning docker and I'm aiming to setup multiple laravel projects, each as a container. Currently I have two projects set up, but whenever I run the docker compose build, and docker compose up on Project 1 and then Project 2; I get a 502 bad gateway error when accessing Project 2, but Project 1 works just fine.
Upon inspecting the /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf file, I noticed that it was using the same port I have applied from Project 1. It seems like they are sharing the same instance/image? Looking for tips on how I can separate them so that they have different values for each container. Since the only solution I was able to find online to override the default port 9000 of php-fpm is by changing the www port in that file.
Project 1 docker-compose.yml
name: test-1
services:
    test-1-srv:
        container_name: test-1-app
        image: php:8.1-fpm
        build:
            context: .
            target: php
            args:
                - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
        environment:
            - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
            - APP_DEBUG=${APP_DEBUG}
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - "33001:8080"

Project 2 docker-compose.yml
name: test-2
services:
    test-2-srv:
        container_name: test-2-app
        image: php:8.1-fpm
        build:
            context: .
            target: php
            args:
                - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
        environment:
            - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
            - APP_DEBUG=${APP_DEBUG}
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - "33002:8080"

As you can see they are pretty much the same. The only difference is the ports used are different. Project 1 uses 33001, Project 2 uses 33002.
Both Dockerfile contains this snippet
FROM php:8.1-fpm as php
RUN sed -i 's/9000/3300X/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

Replacing X as 1 or 2 from the snippet above.
Hoping you guys can guide me to the right direction as I further explore how to work around it.

Did you do a docker compose down atfer changing? Maybe restart your docker service and try the docker compose up again.

@MarkusZeller. I've tried both. I even kept on deleting everything via troubleshoot > reset to factory defaults.

When you run for each compose file, can you share what ports are used? nmap localhost can display ports opened on your localhost or your server machine.

I decided to just overwrite the files entirely. Seemed to work properly now.

So what I did instead is add a zz-docker.conf file with the content
[global]
daemonize = no

[www]
listen = 33002

I then added a COPY command on my Dockerfile
COPY ./docker/php/zz-docker.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

Seems to work properly now.
